# What is a WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraint

I have some auto-generated T-SQL, which is probably valid, but I don't really understand.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
WITH CHECK
CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY];
```

I know what a foreign key constraint is, but what's the `CHECK CHECK`?

Comment: How much "WITH" could a "WITH CHECK CHECK"...?

Comment: @Dodecaphone That depends on how many CHECKS a WITH could CHECK, if a WITH could CHECK CHECKS.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The MSDN documentattion page about [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx) explains these:

- `ALTER TABLE`: modify the table's structure
  (and some of the possible actions/modifications are):

  - `CHECK CONSTRAINT ..`: enable the constraint
  - `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ..`: disable the constraint
    There are also additional, optional steps to do while creating/enabling/disabling a constraint:

    - `WITH CHECK`: check the constraint as well
    - `WITH NOCHECK`: do not check the constraint

In their words:

> ```
> | [ WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK } ] { CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT   
>     { ALL | constraint_name [ ,...n ] }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK`
>   Specifies whether **the data in the table is or is not validated** against **a newly added or re-enabled `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK` constraint**. If not specified, `WITH CHECK` is assumed for new constraints, and `WITH NOCHECK` is assumed for re-enabled constraints.
>
> If you do not want to verify new `CHECK` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraints against existing data, use `WITH NOCHECK`. We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be evaluated in all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed by `WITH NOCHECK` when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the constraint.
>
> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined `WITH NOCHECK`. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled by using `ALTER TABLE` table `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL`.
>
> ...
>
> `{ CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT`
>   Specifies that constraint_name is enabled or disabled. This option can only be used with `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints. When `NOCHECK` is specified, the constraint is disabled and future inserts or updates to the column are not validated against the constraint conditions. `DEFAULT`, `PRIMARY KEY`, and `UNIQUE` constraints cannot be disabled.

Test in [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=12b18072076b9ff852542e54e284a47c):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE a (aid INT PRIMARY KEY);
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO a (aid)
> VALUES (1), (2), (3) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE b 
> ( aid INT,
>   bid INT PRIMARY KEY,
>   CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY]
>     FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES a (aid)
> ) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO b (aid, bid)
> VALUES
>   (1, 11),
>   (1, 12),
>   (2, 21), 
>   (3, 31) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO b (aid, bid)
> VALUES
>   (6, 61),
>   (6, 62) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "My_FORIEGN_KEY". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_792fce5de09f42908c3a0f91421f3522", table "dbo.a", column 'aid'.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM b ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> aid | bid
> --: | --:
>   1 |  11
>   1 |  12
>   2 |  21
>   3 |  31
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE b NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY];   --disable
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO b (aid, bid)
> VALUES
>   (4, 41),
>   (4, 42) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM b ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> aid | bid
> --: | --:
>   1 |  11
>   1 |  12
>   2 |  21
>   3 |  31
>   4 |  41
>   4 |  42
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE b WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY];  
> -- enable constraint without checking existing data
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM b ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> aid | bid
> --: | --:
>   1 |  11
>   1 |  12
>   2 |  21
>   3 |  31
>   4 |  41
>   4 |  42
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO b (aid, bid)
> VALUES
>   (6, 61),
>   (6, 62) ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "My_FORIEGN_KEY". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_792fce5de09f42908c3a0f91421f3522", table "dbo.a", column 'aid'.
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM b ;
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> aid | bid
> --: | --:
>   1 |  11
>   1 |  12
>   2 |  21
>   3 |  31
>   4 |  41
>   4 |  42
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE b WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY];  
> -- check existing data and enable constraint
> ```
>
> GO
>
> ```
> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "My_FORIEGN_KEY". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_792fce5de09f42908c3a0f91421f3522", table "dbo.a", column 'aid'.
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  W.r.t `ALTER TABLE b WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FORIEGN_KEY];  -- enable constraint without checking`, will this mean that the constraint won't check existing data, only new incoming data?

Comment: Exactly. See how the next insert (aid=6) is not allowed but existing rows (with aid=4) are still there.

Comment: That demonstrates it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading the article here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

It tells us:

> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined
> WITH NOCHECK. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled
> by using ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Also, consider this thread on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529941/with-check-add-constraint-followed-by-check-constraint-vs-add-constraint