# Primary key guarantees: duplicates and nullity

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, oracle, sqlite

Oracle allows primary keys to have duplicate and null values.
Using this capability isn't a particularly good idea, but it implies that some of what most developers consider a primary key's guarantees (non-null, unique) are not really guarantees.

```
CREATE TABLE oracle_guarantees (
    ID NUMBER(9,0),
    NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    breed NVARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (1, 'Fuzz Head', 'Tabby');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (2, 'Fluffy Thing', 'Mix');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (2, 'Fluffy Thing', 'Mix');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (3, 'Tiger', 'Tabby');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (4, 'Fur Beast', 'Bengal');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (5, 'Karate', 'Japanese Bobtail');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (6, 'Chairman Meow', 'Chinese Harlequin');
INSERT INTO oracle_guarantees VALUES (NULL, 'No Cat', 'No breed');

CREATE INDEX oracle_guarantees_pk ON oracle_guarantees (ID);
ALTER TABLE oracle_guarantees ADD CONSTRAINT oracle_guarantees_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID) DISABLE KEEP INDEX;
ALTER TABLE oracle_guarantees MODIFY CONSTRAINT oracle_guarantees_pk ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

*SQLite PKs also allow one null but not duplicate values*.

Is it possible to have constraints marked as primary keys which have duplicate values or null values in Microsoft SQL or Postgres?

In other words, can I absolutely rely on PK uniqueness and non-nullity within the documented feature set (ignoring cases like manually edited data files, bugs, or modified server source code)?

---

Further clarification:
I suspect that DBAs and developers work a little more differently than I thought.

Thought exercise:
A developer needs to uniquely identify rows on **any** table (the table structure is unknown at compile time).
[Oracle's documentation on primary key constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) comes up in a search and says:

> A primary key constraint combines a NOT NULL constraint and a unique
>   constraint in a single declaration. That is, it prohibits multiple
>   rows from having the same value in the same column or combination of
>   columns and prohibits values from being null.

The developer then looks for a means to find the primary keys on any table at run time. They probably come across a question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016578/how-to-get-primary-key-column-in-oracle

The top voted answer's query yields:

[image: Results of PK metadata query]

I believe that any reasonable non-DBA person would, at this point, conclude that the `ID` column cannot have NULL or duplicate values. This conclusion is not true.

- Is it Oracle's fault? No.
- Is the table properly designed? No.
- Are the statements to create such a table complex? *Immaterial.*
- Is the Id column a "real" primary key? Maybe not, but this is more a philosophical matter. `ID` *is* listed (and is shown as 
  "ENABLED") by the query in the top-rated SO answer to the linked question above. Perhaps that question needs to add a check for validation, but I have never once seen anyone check for this in code, nor do any answers in that thread or related threads I have found.

Ergo, in the real world, an arbitrary table can have a primary key (by definition of `all_constraints.constraint_type`) which has duplicate values. And NULL values.

I now know that software must also ensure that the constraint is validated. Excellent! That provides the *guarantee* I need.

The question is: Is it possible to have a primary key (as defined by DBMS metadata) that has NULL or duplicate values in PostgreSQL or Microsoft SQL?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57761/discussion-on-question-by-charles-burns-primary-key-guarantees-duplicates-and-n). Please continue there. Further chat-like comments may be simply removed.

Answer (score 8):

> Oracle allows primary keys to have duplicate and null values.

Not really. What you have managed to create - after a series of complicated statements - is an enabled but **not validated** constraint. Which means that Oracle will check inserts and updates (for uniqueness) but there may be left existing duplicates. So it is a PK only in name. It's a not-validated constraint so not really a PK.

> In other words, can I absolutely rely on PK uniqueness and non-nullity within the documented feature set (ignoring cases like manually edited data files, bugs, or modified server source code)?
>
> More context: I am working on an application that displays records and allows a user to delete them on any arbitrary table. When dealing with an arbitrary table, I need to use metadata and other means to determine which guarantees I have. Much database development is about guarantees -- guarantees that a large transaction will commit or not (but not partially commit). Guarantees that a successfully modified row stays modified. And guarantees that a primary key uniquely refers to exactly one row.

Yes, you can rely but only if your application reads the metadata and all the details - which may differ from DBMS to DBMS.

- SQL Server allows for disabled constraints? The application has to consider this when reading and interpreting the metadata tables.
- Oracle allows for disabled or non-validated constraints? The application has to consider those options too, accordingly.
- Postgres allows for some different weird scenarios? It has to consider them, too.

Another possible option - which may or may not be an option for you - is if the application is the only application that creates, deletes and modifies database objects or if all applications that do so are under your or a single control. Then it can rely on the soundness of the metadata ("consider only unique constraints") without checking for these details / rare cases - because it can rely that no such rare case is ever created in the first place.

With your conclusions:

> Is it Oracle's fault? No.

I agree. I don't know why this was allowed but it probably solves some problem. And it probably was meant to be used only temporarily - e.g. during an import from another source to a database.

> Is the table properly designed? No.
>
> Are the statements to create such a table complex? Immaterial.

I agree, too, on both.

> Is the Id column a "real" primary key? Maybe not, but this is more a philosophical matter. ID is listed (and is shown as "ENABLED") by the query in the top-rated SO answer to the linked question above. Perhaps that question needs to add a check for validation, but I have never once seen anyone check for this in code, nor do any answers in that thread or related threads I have found.

We come to the same conclusion: ***needs to add a check for validation.***

---

As for what other possibilities exist in SQL Server and Postgres:

- SQL Server:

  - `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints **cannot** be disabled.
  - Unique indexes **can be disabled**. They can also be **re-enabled without check** which would result in a situation very similar to the "enabled non-validated" in Oracle.
  - `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints **can be disabled**. They can be **re-enabled without check**, too.
    See [`ALTER TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) and [Disable indexes and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/disable-indexes-and-constraints) for details. My answer in this question: [What is a `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167861/what-is-a-with-check-check-constraint/167866#167866) explains options and the syntax, which differs from Oracle's.
- PostgreSQL:

  - `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE` and `EXCLUDE` constraints **cannot** be disabled.
  - `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints **cannot** be disabled. They can be **created with the `NOT VALID` option** though (which means that they are enabled without checking existing rows, as in SQL Server). See [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Within SQL Server a [primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys) is unique within the confines of the object, and cannot contain null values (in fact the column must be created with a not null constraint in order for it to be used in a primary key).

It is possible to create [unique constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints), which will be unique, but will also allow for a null value.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [PostgreSQL documentation on Primary Keys](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS):

> **5.3.4. Primary Keys**
>
> A primary key constraint indicates that a column, or group of columns,
>   can be used as a unique identifier for rows in the table. This
>   requires that the values be both unique and not null. So, the
>   following two table definitions accept the same data
>
> [...]
>
> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index
>   on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will
>   force the column(s) to be marked NOT NULL.

So, in practice, it agrees with MS SQL Server; and the [2008 SQL Standard (draft from 2006)](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip):

> A primary key constraint is a unique constraint that specifies PRIMARY
>   KEY. A primary key constraint is satisfied if and only if no two rows
>   in a table have the same non-null values in the unique columns and
>   none of the values in the specified column or columns are the null
>   value.

Comment: One can respect SQL servers choice of excluding null, on the other hand a ((null, null), (null, 1), (1, null), (1, 1)) is also a duplicate free unique set of keys in a model where null is allowed.